# Crear una función que permita intercambiar un item que se está moviendo con el ratón por un item que esta en un slot en un inventario en pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy intentado crear un sistema de inventario que se parezca al de minecraft, por lo que cuando alguien hace click sobre el ítem entonces el ítem se comienza a mover con el mouse y cuando se vuelve a hacer click entonces o se saca del inventario o se coloca en un slot dependiendo de donde este el mouse, he conseguido que se pueda sacar el ítem del inventario y que se logre mover si se hace click sobre el, mi problema es cuando quiero intercambiar ese ítem que se esta moviendo con otro que está en un slot, lo único que he hecho es que los ítems se intercambien entre los slots de manera inmediata pero no he conseguido hacer que el slot que estaba en el mouse se convierta en el del slot y el que estaba en el slot se convierta en el que sea arrastrado y he usado una tercera variable para el momento del intercambio pero aun así no logro que funcione:

```
import pygame
import random
from .Config import *

class Inventario:
    def __init__(self, player, totalslots, cols, rows):
        self.player = player
        self.totalSlots = totalslots
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
        self.inventory_slots = []
        self.appendSlots()

        self.movingitem = None
        self.movingitemslot = None
        self.display = False
        self.moving = False

    def addItemInv(self, item, slot=None):

        if slot == None:
            for slots in self.inventory_slots:
                if slots.item == None:
                    slots.item = item
                    slots.cant += 1
                    break
                else:
                    if slots.item.id == item.id:
                        if slots.item.is_acum and slots.cant < item.max_acum:
                            slots.cant += 1
                            break
                        elif slots.cant > item.max_acum:
                            break


        if slot != None:
            if slot.item != None:
                self.swap_items(slot)
            else:
                slot.item = item
                slot.cant = self.slot_cant
                self.moving = False

    def removeItemInv(self, item):
        for slot in self.inventory_slots:
            if slot.item == item:
                if slot.item.is_acum:
                    slot.cant = 0
                slot.item = None
                break

    def swap_items(self, slot):
        res = None
        if self.movingitem != None:
            if slot.item != None:
                res = self.movingitem
                self.movingitem = slot.item
                slot.item = res
                res.is_moving = True


    def moveItem(self, screen):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for slot in self.inventory_slots:
            if slot.draw(screen).collidepoint(mouse):
                if slot.item != None:
                    slot.item.is_moving = True
                    self.movingitem = slot.item
                    self.movingitemslot = slot
                    self.slot_cant = slot.cant
                    self.movingitemslot.cant = 0
                    self.moving = True
                    break

    def placeItem(self, screen, grupo):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        enter = True
        cant = 0

        for slots in self.inventory_slots:
            if slots.draw(screen).collidepoint(mouse) and self.movingitem != None:
                enter = True
                self.removeItemInv(self.movingitem)
                self.addItemInv(self.movingitem, slots)
                break
            elif not slots.draw(screen).collidepoint(mouse):
                enter = False
                if self.movingitem.is_acum:
                    cant = self.slot_cant
                continue

        if not enter:
            self.removeItemInv(self.movingitem)
            self.player.drop(self.movingitem, grupo, cant)

        if self.movingitem != None:
            self.movingitem.is_moving = False
            self.movingitem = None
            self.movingitemslot = None
```